# How to execute files directly from Notepad++

Tags: javascript, node.js, editor

For the past few weeks, I have been working with Node JS a lot, and i have found it  pretty annoying to have to execute the file through cmd every time i want to test.

To make my life easier, I have made a batch file that executes my file for me. My question is how do I execute files directly from notepad++?

Is there a menu for it? Currently on my left I have a menu that lets me navigate between my files easily. On my right, I have a NppFTP UI that lets me connect to the FTP server, if I need to work on files that are not on my system.

I highly suspect that there is a way to execute files directly from Notepad++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although my answer doesn't directly answer your question, it will resolve the problem you were facing in the first place.

There is something called **nodemon** which will restart your node process as soon as you save your changes. It's very simple to use:

To install :

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

To use:

```
nodemon app.js
```

or Just [it automatically grabs the default app.js file or other]

```
nodemon
```

You can learn more about this here:
http://nodemon.io/